# Configuring a Maven project to fail when a Lombok usage is flagged as ERROR on lombok.config

Tags: java, maven, lombok

I try to configure a Maven project to fail when a Lombok usage is flagged as ERROR on lombok.config

But it only writes an INFO log with the error message, it doesn't fail the build.
Is there a configuration for that ?

Here is a sample project. Regards.

**lombok.config**

```
config.stopBubbling = true
lombok.data.flagUsage = ERROR
```

**src/main/lombok/Example.java**

```
@lombok.Data
public class Example {
    private String msg;
}
```

**src/main/java/Test.java**

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Example ex = new Example();
        ex.setMsg("Hello");
    }
}
```

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>example</groupId>
    <artifactId>example</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.12</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                <artifactId>lombok-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.18.12.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>delombok</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

**mvn compile**

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] ------------------------< org.example:example >-------------------------
[INFO] Building example 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] --- lombok-maven-plugin:1.18.12.0:delombok (default) @ example ---
example\src\main\lombok\Example.java:1: error: Use of @Data is flagged according to lombok configuration.
@lombok.Data
^
[INFO] Delombok complete.
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ example ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory example\src\main\resources
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ example ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 2 source files to example\target\classes
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: It's probably because you are using `delombok`. A regular compilation would fail. Do you have to use `delombok`, or could you switch to regular (annotation-processing-enabled) compilation?

Comment: Indeed, for a sample project the annotationProcessor solve the problem.
Unfortunately for my real project (multi-modules with Spring-Boot, using Lombok for Jackson's DTO or Hibernate's Entity) to achieve all goals delombok works rather not bad while annotationProcessor not at all.

Comment: Jackson and Hibernate should work without problems with regular lombok compilation. If there are no other annotation processors (or javadoc) involved, I discourage from using `delombok`.

Comment: Following @JanRieke advice discouraging delombok I refocused on annotation processors and find a `<compilerArgument>-proc:none</compilerArgument>` in the configuration which explain why it was not working. In the end I succeeded and that should meet my need. Thanks.